How to change the label color of a disabled textInput?
I do not understand how the label of a shiny textInput is properly addressed with CSS. I found many different ways of changing the label properties while searching, but while trying to adapt it to a tags$head(tags$style()) format in my ui, found that some work and some don't. I think this is important to understand when trying to change the label reactively. While I am able to change the default label color, I am unable to change it to a different color when textInput is disabled like I can for the text input field and placeholder.
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
  tags$head(
    #enabled settings:
    tags$style(HTML(".form-control {color:#3c8930; background:#c5e6c0;}")),
    tags$style(HTML(".form-control::placeholder{color:#7fbc75;}")),
    tags$style(HTML("#name-label {color: #3c8930;}")),
    #tags$style(HTML(".form-control-label {color: #3c8930;}")), #this does not work
    #tags$style(HTML("label.form-control-label {color: #3c8930;}")), #this does not work
    #tags$style(HTML("label.control-label {color: #3c8930;}")), #this works but changes all labels, even if they're not textInput

    #disabled settings:
    tags$style(HTML(".form-control.disabled{color:#c74545; background:#f7c2c2;}")),
    tags$style(HTML(".form-control.disabled::placeholder{color:#c17575;}")),
    #tags$style(HTML(" ... how to change the label color here?..."))
  ), 
  textInput(inputId = "name", 
            label='Label',
            placeholder = "Placeholder"),
  checkboxInput('disable','disable', value=F),
  radioButtons("name2", label="Label2",inline = TRUE, c("A", "B"))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  observe(
    if(input$disable){
      shinyjs::disable('name')
     }else{
      shinyjs::enable('name')
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

I was able to do a workaround by reactively updating the color in the observer, but in my full app I also work with shinyFeedback and those updates override any feedback coloring of the label.
library(shinyFeedback)

ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
  shinyFeedback::useShinyFeedback(),
  tags$head(
    #enabled settings:
    tags$style(HTML(".form-control {color:#3c8930; background:#c5e6c0;}")),
    tags$style(HTML(".form-control::placeholder{color:#7fbc75;}")),
 
    #disabled settings:
    tags$style(HTML(".form-control.disabled{color:#c74545; background:#f7c2c2;}")),
    tags$style(HTML(".form-control.disabled::placeholder{color:#c17575;}")),
  ), 
  textInput(inputId = "name", 
            label=tags$p('Label', style = "color:#3c8930;", id="name_label"),
            placeholder = "Placeholder"),
  checkboxInput('disable','disable', value=F),
  radioButtons("name2", label="Label2",inline = TRUE, c("A", "B"))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  observe(
    if(input$disable){
      shinyjs::disable('name')
      shinyjs::html("name_label", "<p style='color:#c74545'>Label</p>")
    }else{
      shinyjs::enable('name')
      shinyjs::html("name_label", "<p style='color:#3c8930'>Label</p>")
    }
  )
    
    observe(
      shinyFeedback::feedbackWarning("name", input$name2=='B', "B is selected", icon=NULL)
    )
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)


For clarification: What is your desired answer here? Shall the first code block be edited such that the label color changes dynamically? Or shall the second code block be edited (what exactly are the problems inside the second block, I suspect the orange color)?

The first one is preferred so the label color is dynamically updated when the input is disabled. The second was merely my attempt at a workaround, but is not the preferred approach as everything being defined in the ui (or a separate css file) is much cleaner.

There are several possibilities for changing the color. One is that if the disable/enable button is clicked you change the class of the element:
observe(
  if(input$disable){
    shinyjs::disable('name')
    shinyjs::runjs('document.getElementById("name-label").className = "control-label-disabled"')
  }else{
    shinyjs::enable('name')
    shinyjs::runjs('document.getElementById("name-label").className = "control-label"')
  }
)

This would affect only the element with id = 'name-label', but you can of course change the selector to also target other elements. Once you've done this, you can define the css for these classes, e.g.
tags$style(HTML(".control-label {color: #3c8930;}
                 .control-label-disabled {color: #c74545;}"))

and then the style will change. A complete example is below. Notice that therefore I also included another border-color for the disabled form-control since in your example there remains a small green border around the red box which one may not want to have.

library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
  tags$head(
    #enabled settings:
    tags$style(HTML(".form-control {color:#3c8930; background:#c5e6c0;}")),
    tags$style(HTML(".form-control::placeholder{color:#7fbc75;}")),
    tags$style(HTML(".control-label {color: #3c8930;}")),
    
    #disabled settings:
    tags$style(HTML(".form-control.disabled{
                        color:#c74545; 
                        background:#f7c2c2;
                        border-color:#c74545; 
                     }")),
    tags$style(HTML(".form-control.disabled::placeholder{color:#c17575;}")),
    tags$style(HTML(".control-label-disabled {color: #c74545;}"))
  ), 
  textInput(inputId = "name", 
            label='Label',
            placeholder = "Placeholder"),
  checkboxInput('disable','disable', value=F),
  radioButtons("name2", label="Label2",inline = TRUE, c("A", "B"))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  observe(
    if(input$disable){
      shinyjs::disable('name')
      shinyjs::runjs('document.getElementById("name-label").className = "control-label-disabled"')
    }else{
      shinyjs::enable('name')
      shinyjs::runjs('document.getElementById("name-label").className = "control-label"')
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

